# two matrix output into a single txt file in matlab

Tags: matlab, fileoutputstream

I've two matrix output from two Matlab scripts and I'd like to write both results in different columns of the same GUI output in a txt file. 
Could you please help me?

Comment: `horzcat` the two matrices if they have the same number of rows, pad it with zeros or NaN if they do not have the same number of rows. Use `reshape` if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I tried some different methods (try to create cell array, or use `fprintf` for arrays of different sizes) and understood that [@GameOfThrows's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4291805/gameofthrows) method is really works.
I realize it in this way:

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5];
y = [10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90];
[m,i] = max( [numel(x)  numel(y)]);
if i == 1
    y(end+1:numel(x))=NaN;
else
    x(end+1:numel(y))=NaN;
end
a = [x; y];
fileID = fopen('data1.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID,'%6.2f %12.2f\r\n',a);
```

My `data1.txt`:

```
  1.00        10.00
  2.00        20.00
  3.00        30.00
  4.00        40.00
  5.00        50.00
   NaN        60.00
   NaN        70.00
   NaN        80.00
   NaN        90.00
```